# Transforming pandas dataframe into a summary table based on a list of values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to create a summary table from a dataframe that looks like below example. The columns have a set list of unique values.

```py
tdf = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["ind1", "ind2", "ind1", "ind3", "ind3", "ind1", "ind1"],
                   "B": ["ind3", "ind1", "ind3", "ind1", "ind1","ind3", "ind2"],
                   "C": ["ind1","ind1","ind2","ind2","ind3","ind3","ind3"],
                   "D": ["ind3","ind1","ind2","ind3","ind2","ind1","ind3"],
                   "E": ["ind1","ind3","ind1","ind1","ind2","ind2","ind2"]})
```

I'd then need to create a new table-like object that has a header that correspond to the columns and 3 rows with frequency counts of the set index values.

```py
setvalues = ['ind1','ind2','ind3']

result = pd.DataFrame({"A": [4,1,2],
                   "B": [3,1,3],
                   "C": [2,2,3],
                   "D": [2,2,3],
                   "E": [3,3,1]})
```

I tried pivot tables but it wasn't returning the required format. In Excel I could just set the index values and do a simple COUNTIF on the columns but I am struggling to implement it in Python.

Answer (score 2):

Here we can using `value_counts`

```
tdf.apply(pd.Series.value_counts)
      A  B  C  D  E
ind1  4  3  2  2  3
ind2  1  1  2  2  3
ind3  2  3  3  3  1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

tdf = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["ind1", "ind2", "ind1", "ind3", "ind3", "ind1", "ind1"],
                   "B": ["ind3", "ind1", "ind3", "ind1", "ind1","ind3", "ind2"],
                   "C": ["ind1","ind1","ind2","ind2","ind3","ind3","ind3"],
                   "D": ["ind3","ind1","ind2","ind3","ind2","ind1","ind3"],
                   "E": ["ind1","ind3","ind1","ind1","ind2","ind2","ind2"]})

full = tdf.apply(pd.value_counts).fillna(0);
print(full)
```

Comment: Thanks both, they work perfectly! If you don't mind me asking, how would the code change if my original dataframe had two more columns (gender and market, both having two unique values in each) and the output dataframe would need to be grouped by the additional two columns so I could visualize the output with a 2x2 facetgrid format? I assume I would need to add a groupby step somewhere but couldn't figure out how to do it.